in matlab, cmdscale does not respect the matrix distances
I am trying to plot the distance between 20 dyads from a 20x20 matrix by using the cmdscale function, but the resulting plot does not match the matrix : some of my dyads are the closest on the plot while there are in fact not the closest when I am looking at the distances in the matrix (e.g 15 and 7 or 24 and 8).
The matrix is a mean of several distances by dyad, could the issue come from that, i.e. could it be linked to how MDS attempt to model similarity or dissimilarity of my data?
Thank you in advance for your help!
This is my matrix :
Columns 1 through 8
     0    2.9653    3.2230    2.8584    3.1432    3.2808    3.0862    2.9497
2.9653         0    3.0887    3.1811    2.6100    2.8237    2.4911    2.7203
3.2230    3.0887         0    3.5408    3.3518    2.9686    2.9160    2.8658
2.8584    3.1811    3.5408         0    2.9473    3.2303    3.3080    3.0548
3.1432    2.6100    3.3518    2.9473         0    2.6647    3.3269    3.0144
3.2808    2.8237    2.9686    3.2303    2.6647         0    3.0047    3.0691
3.0862    2.4911    2.9160    3.3080    3.3269    3.0047         0    3.0322
2.9497    2.7203    2.8658    3.0548    3.0144    3.0691    3.0322         0
3.1762    3.0108    3.3194    3.1150    3.2592    3.1145    3.1722    3.0799
3.1882    2.9232    3.0836    3.3319    3.2622    3.2148    3.0828    3.2406
2.4554    2.7071    3.0788    3.1644    2.7968    3.0855    3.0433    2.7806
3.2932    2.8705    3.1786    3.4448    3.3172    3.2933    2.8854    3.2879
3.1120    3.1188    2.6459    3.2080    3.2328    3.1568    3.1785    3.1437
3.3260    3.1060    2.6544    3.1201    3.1650    3.0548    2.8884    2.8402
3.2803    2.5523    3.2278    3.2217    2.9949    2.7493    2.7412    3.1340
3.1909    2.8943    3.3254    3.0940    3.0320    3.2344    3.3345    2.9592
3.0632    3.0596    3.2684    3.0824    3.0228    2.9901    3.2752    2.9603
2.5344    2.9183    3.2891    3.0900    3.4848    3.3236    3.1210    2.9667
2.9851    3.0473    2.9082    2.8537    2.8224    2.9758    3.4063    2.9222
2.6194    2.9375    3.0021    3.1546    3.1915    3.1921    3.2581    3.0678

Columns 9 through 16
3.1762    3.1882    2.4554    3.2932    3.1120    3.3260    3.2803    3.1909
3.0108    2.9232    2.7071    2.8705    3.1188    3.1060    2.5523    2.8943
3.3194    3.0836    3.0788    3.1786    2.6459    2.6544    3.2278    3.3254
3.1150    3.3319    3.1644    3.4448    3.2080    3.1201    3.2217    3.0940
3.2592    3.2622    2.7968    3.3172    3.2328    3.1650    2.9949    3.0320
3.1145    3.2148    3.0855    3.2933    3.1568    3.0548    2.7493    3.2344
3.1722    3.0828    3.0433    2.8854    3.1785    2.8884    2.7412    3.3345
3.0799    3.2406    2.7806    3.2879    3.1437    2.8402    3.1340    2.9592
     0    3.2420    3.2435    3.5123    2.9707    2.6942    3.2396    3.3114
3.2420         0    3.0433    2.9127    3.1470    3.3033    3.2497    3.1586
3.2435    3.0433         0    3.1954    3.0412    3.2604    3.0496    2.9285
3.5123    2.9127    3.1954         0    3.2678    3.2255    3.2575    3.1056
2.9707    3.1470    3.0412    3.2678         0    3.3503    3.5184    3.5914
2.6942    3.3033    3.2604    3.2255    3.3503         0    3.0475    2.7524
3.2396    3.2497    3.0496    3.2575    3.5184    3.0475         0    3.2534
3.3114    3.1586    2.9285    3.1056    3.5914    2.7524    3.2534         0
3.1723    3.3090    2.1651    3.5620    3.3848    3.1173    3.1470    2.6516
3.2338    3.0103    2.9089    3.2281    2.6424    3.0992    3.4654    3.0025
3.1500    2.9570    3.1055    3.0921    2.9609    2.9692    3.1632    3.0927
3.0246    3.2398    2.0885    3.4584    2.9437    3.3885    3.1736    3.4367

Columns 17 through 20
3.0632    2.5344    2.9851    2.6194
3.0596    2.9183    3.0473    2.9375
3.2684    3.2891    2.9082    3.0021
3.0824    3.0900    2.8537    3.1546
3.0228    3.4848    2.8224    3.1915
2.9901    3.3236    2.9758    3.1921
3.2752    3.1210    3.4063    3.2581
2.9603    2.9667    2.9222    3.0678
3.1723    3.2338    3.1500    3.0246
3.3090    3.0103    2.9570    3.2398
2.1651    2.9089    3.1055    2.0885
3.5620    3.2281    3.0921    3.4584
3.3848    2.6424    2.9609    2.9437
3.1173    3.0992    2.9692    3.3885
3.1470    3.4654    3.1632    3.1736
2.6516    3.0025    3.0927    3.4367
     0    2.9237    2.8699    2.8729
2.9237         0    3.1148    2.6957
2.8699    3.1148         0    3.1689
2.8729    2.6957    3.1689         0

This is my code :
figure

[Y,eigvals] = cmdscale(mtrx_to_plot*100);
plot(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),'.','MarkerSize',20)
text(Y(:,1), Y(:,2), arrayfun(@num2str, node_labels_G, 'UniformOutput', false), 'VerticalAlignment','bottom','HorizontalAlignment','right')
xlabel('km')
ylabel('km')

**This is the resulting plot **:


As per the documentation:

[Y,e] = cmdscale(D) also returns the eigenvalues of Y*Y'. When D is
Euclidean, the first p elements of e are positive, the rest zero. If
the first k elements of e are much larger than the remaining (n-k),
then you can use the first k columns of Y as k-dimensional points
whose inter-point distances approximate D. This can provide a useful
dimension reduction for visualization, e.g., for k = 2

Running your code gives the following eigenvalues:
108515.517929691
96468.2555527725
82677.0188819042
77639.1183543658
70605.7164580977
65554.6563703696
52148.2959167582
46334.8176979909
44060.0550566365
41177.4445305762
35558.8948113113
35168.7111495575
33497.5408730358
30896.8813349555
25821.7237802443
23466.4797806560
16056.1920820620
13412.9555068766
5512.63823213849
8.79260170539034e-11

Only, say, one to four of your eigenvalues are significantly lower than the others. It means than you need a minimum of 16 to 19 dimensions to represent your data without losing too much accuracy.
This loss of accuracy is actually illustrated by what you observe when trying to represent your data using only the first 2 columns of Y.
TLDR
Your cmdscale output is correct, your 2d representation extracted from it is not accurate

So your data comes from measurements of distances in a 2d plane? If so, you should only get 2 significative eigenvalues. Are you sure your measurements / distances calculations are correct?

Thank you so much for the explanantion! I don't understand why I would get such small eigenvalues, all distances have been measured during an experiment and I just wanted to plot them, would you have a recommandation or a workaround that eigenvalues issue? I have tried to use the following to recreate the graph, at least with proportionnal edges, but l am not completly satisifed:
G = graph(s,t,weights);
p = plot(G,'Layout','force','EdgeLabel',G.Edges.Weight);
Thank you again!

So, all your distances come from measurements that were made in a 2d/3d space? If so there must be a problem either with the measurement or with the calculation of the distances between the points
